# NameError: name 'WIDTH_DEGREES' is not defined

Tags: python, class-method, python-3.7

I'm trying to do this [MOOC](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4302126-decouvrez-la-programmation-orientee-objet-avec-python?status=published)

And on this [class](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4302126-decouvrez-la-programmation-orientee-objet-avec-python/4312971-creez-votre-premiere-zone)

I wrote exactly the same code but it doesn't work the same for me. I don't understand.

My full code is on [github](https://github.com/jeremytrindade/decouvrez-la-programmation-orientee-objet-avec-python/blob/master/model.py).

```
class Zone:

    ZONE = []
    MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES = -180
    MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES = 180
    MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREES = -90
    MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREES = 90
    WIDTH_DEGREES = 1
    HEIGHT_DEGREES = 1

    def __init__(self, corner1, corner2):
        self.corner1 = corner1
        self.corner2 = corner2
        self.inhabitants = 0

    @classmethod # etand donner qu'on ne sommes plus dans l'instance, masi oui dans la classe il faut changer self par cls
    def initialize_zones(cls):
        for latitude in range(cls.MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREES):
            for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, WIDTH_DEGREES):
                bottom_left_corner = Position(longitude, latitude)
                top_right_corner = Position(longitude + cls.WIDTH_DEGREES, latitude + cls.HEIGHT_DEGREES)
                zone = Zone(bottom_left_corner, top_right_corner)
                cls.ZONE.append(zone)
                #zone = Zone(bottem_letf_corner, top_right_corner)
        print(len(cls.ZONES))


def main():

    for agent_attributes in json.load(open("agents-100k.json")):
        latitude = agent_attributes.pop('latitude')
        longitude = agent_attributes.pop('longitude')
        position = Position(longitude, latitude)
        agent = Agent(position, **agent_attributes)
        Zone.initialize_zones()

main()
```

**ERROR was:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "model.py", line 64, in
>
> ```
> main()
> ```
>
> File "model.py", line 62, in main
>
> ```
> Zone.initialize_zones()
> ```
>
> File "model.py", line 46, in initialize_zones
>
> ```
> for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, WIDTH_DEGREES):
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'WIDTH_DEGREES' is not defined

Comment: `cls.WIDTH_DEGREES` not just `WIDTH_DEGREES`?

Comment: Pay attention to tags, this is not git nor github related question.

Comment: Ok thanks i will remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after all, I had two errors, one of them was the CLS, which I had accidentally tried to insert, but since I had gotten a mistake in it and since I did not pay attention I had two instead of one because in the print it was badly written too.

First of all, as @FHTMichell told and right was:

```
for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, WIDTH_DEGREES)
```

should be

```
for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.WIDTH_DEGREES)
```

And on:

```
@classmethod
def initialize_zones(cls):
```

the print was wrong too:

```
print(len(cls.ZONES))
```

should be

```
print(len(cls.ZONE))
```

Thanks @user2653663 too for helping.

Answer (score 2):

`for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, WIDTH_DEGREES)`

should be

`for longitude in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREES, cls.WIDTH_DEGREES)`

---

Next time, post your full error traceback

Comment: now is other insue, i figure out and i will post the full correction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `WIDTH_DEGREES` instead of `cls.WIDTH_DEGREES` in your `for longitude ...` loop.

Comment: Thanks for helping mate btw check my answer